# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1 on backpressed fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have code in my MainActivity like below

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
    String title = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getTag();
    if (title != null) {
        method.ShowFullScreen(false);
        toolbar.setTitle(title);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        getWindow().clearFlags(1024);
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

In my Fragment, I am going from category fragment to search fragment like below

```
SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("search_menu", tag);
            bundle.putString("typeLayout", "Landscape");
            searchFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout_main, searchFragment, tag).addToBackStack(category_name).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Now when pressing back from the search fragment, I am getting an error like below

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.myapp.Activity.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:225)
```

I am learning android and do not get an idea of why it's getting crashed. Let me know if someone can help me with solving the issue.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to not replace current fragment, add new on top of current fragment and hide current fragment.

```
SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("search_menu", tag);
            bundle.putString("typeLayout", "Landscape");
            searchFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())
                    .getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.frameLayout_main, searchFragment, tag)
                    .addToBackStack(category_name)
                    .hide(currentFragment)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Your array has a size of one and the only index available is at 0, not at 1. Follow your stacktrace to line 438 in ArrayList.java or line 225 in MainActivity.java. Inspect the index values, like the return value of getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount().

Comment: can you please describe more, why I have size 1? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using **replace** method for fragments and also you are adding fragments to backstack. WWhich is not a good approach really. You need to use **add** in place of replace while beginning a transaction for fragment.

Replacethis

```
.replace(R.id.frameLayout_main, searchFragment, tag)
```

with this

```
.add(R.id.frameLayout_main, searchFragment, tag)
```

Also to tackle this crash , replace below line

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0)
```

with this one

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0 &&
   getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() < getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this, in your fragment

```
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("search_menu", tag);
        bundle.putString("typeLayout", "Landscape");
        SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
        searchFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frameLayout_main, searchFragment)
                .addToBackStack(category_name)
                .commit();
```

And in your Activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {

        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } 
}
```